# Starting a project like picasa

Tags: project-management, project, projects-and-solutions, new-project

I am starting a new project which have an interface like picasa 3. Please let me know what all documents i have to prepare in advance before starting the project. Right now i am only developer but in the future other developers may join.

Is there any third-party components which will help me simplify the task of theming and creating buttons?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Not to be rude, and not to invalidate the question, but if you are asking at this high level of generality, it suggests you do not have a lot of experience with developing large projects.

Comment: Also, your question is rather confusing - is it about creating buttons, or project management?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your question is actually 2 questions. For things to prepare when starting a development project:

- schedule and cost estimation report (use a [cost estimation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_development_estimation_software))
- project design specification
- project logical block diagram (can be UML or just Visio)
- technological feasibility report
- business presentation based on the above documents

depending on your venture model, you may be required to present your investors with further reports and presentations.